# Updating a Progress Bar with RxJava

Tags: android, progress-bar, rx-java, android-progressbar

I have a problem to update progress for ProgressBar with RxJava on Android. 
I want to update **1%** after delay **500 miliseconds** (***from 0% -> 50%***) with RxJava. But when I code such as (*code in below*), progress update to **50%** after delay ***500 miliseconds***.

Below is my code:

```
Observable.range(0,50)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(integer -> mProgressBar.setProgress(integer));
```

Answer (score 0):

`delay` shifts the entire sequence in time; the relative time between subsequent items remains the same. Have you considered using [`intervalRange()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#intervalRange-long-long-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-io.reactivex.Scheduler-)?

```
Observable.intervalRange(0L, 50L, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(v -> mProgressBar.setProgress(v.intValue()));
```

For 1.x, you can concatMap it into timers:

```
 Observable.range(0, 50)
 .concatMap(v -> 
     Observable.timer(
         10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
     )
     .map(w -> v)
 )
 .subscribe(v -> mProgressBar.setProgress(v.intValue()));
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. But I can't find intervalRange() when use Observable. in lib import rx.Observable. Can you help me with problem.